# Sharing content via Twitter URL not working

Tags: javascript

Im currently using a JS that I found on a related question, but i'm currently facing two problems.

First: The anchor is not working on Firefox, it simply pops a blank page. 
Note: It works in Chrome and Edge

The second problem, which is not really a problem but a preference. Is it possible to not tweet the current URL where the button is being clicked?

Thanks so much advance for any tips

```
var twitterUsuario = 'User';

function tweetCurrentPage() {
    window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url='+escape(window.location.href)+'&text='+ document.getElementById('suNombre').innerHTML + ' tengo un mensaje muy importante para ti ' + 'desde @' + twitterUsuario, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');    return false; 
}

<a href="javascript:tweetCurrentPage()" target="_blank" alt="Tweet this"><span>Tweet</span></a>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) as per StackOverflow guidelines.

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated, it is entirely possible to tweet the current page, and you really should be using AJAX to post to the Twitter API rather than opening up a Twitter window.